# 'flash flood occurred' or 'flash flooding occurred', which is correct?

Tags: word-usage

> A) The **flash flood** occurred as a result of the downpour at a forest.

or

> B) The **flash flooding** occurred as a result of the downpour at a forest.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, it just depends how you want to say it

> A *flash flood occurred* due to heavy rains.
>
> *Flash flooding occurred* do to heavy rains.

Both would be understood to have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

> A) The **flash flood** occurred as a result of the downpour *in the* forest.

Here, *flash flood* is a weather event, like a snowstorm or a cyclone.

> B) The **flash flooding** occurred as a result of the downpour *in the* forest.

Here, *flash flooding* refers to the water that is flooding everything in its path.

*in* is used since a forest is a large area, and the downpour is somewhere within it. *the* because as a specific event it refers to a specific forest.